# How to ask if anyone knows about something?

Tags: sentence-choice

Situation : I want to ask every person in my class if anyone know what is the day of today.

I am deciding about these sentence below. Which one sounds more natural?

1. Who knows what is this day?
2. Does anyone know what is this day?

If there are any sentences can be used in this situation please tell me.

Thank you so much.

Comment: These aren't natural. Try "Does anyone know what day it is today?" or "Who knows what day it is today?" or shorter "Does anyone know what day it is?" or "Who knows what day it is?" or even shorter "What day is it?"

Comment: Do you want them to answer "It's Monday",  or do you want the to answer "It's Valentine's day"  (or something else)

Comment: Not "Who knows what is this day?", but "Who knows what today is?".